# Is it possible to show, inside my app, the list of steps obtained using Google Maps Directions API?

Tags: google-maps

I want to show the list of steps from origin to destination (inside my application), after using the Google Maps Directions Api. I want to know if I can do it or I'm violating the License Restrictions written here [navigation_restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions) in section "No navigation"?
I've understood that I cannot use these informations to implement a real-time navigation. I just want to display the steps of the route.

Thank you.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question, always include clear description, preferably with a code example, of what you have already tried and how it failed or wasn't sufficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues), not coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

At least is a Navigation or asset tracking app, there is no issue in showing the steps in a list. Make sure that if you are displaying this list in a map that is a Google Maps ;).